# Centered table and margins are not working?

Tags: html, css, centering

I have noticed that this forum I have written is fine in most browsers although in IE8 its to the left and not centered.

Its CSS is `margin: auto auto`, which works in most browsers.

I don't want to resort to going old fashioned and putting align="center" in the actual table properties.

Can anyone explain it ?

http://forum.bestlincs.co.uk/

Comment: Is the width of the table fixed?

Comment: Try declaring a doctype e.g. <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Comment: jdwire yes the table is fixed at 900px, Billy - i have done this and it did fix it however its very spaced out now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix the centering issue you need to specify a doctype like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

To fix your spacing problem you need to look at the box model. Without the doctype your site was using the old box model which is:

```
width = width + border + padding

and

height = height + border + padding
```

You need to revsisit that now like so:

```
width = width - (border + padding)
height = height - (border + padding)
```

Hope that makes sense. You should use the above to adjust the width / height of any elemts on your page such as DIVs TDs etc.

Answer (score 3):

You have (or rather, when I started writing this answer, you *had*) no Doctype, so IE assumes the site is using layout techniques from the IE 5 era and partially emulates that browser.

Add a Doctype to trigger Standards mode.

The HTML 5 Doctype looks like the best match for your site:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

Comment: I tried the one from above and it now makes it all spaced out and larger, although it does fix the center issues

Comment: I've just tried <!DOCTYPE HTML> and again its all spaced out, i wanted it condensed like it was before i put in a doctype

Comment: @Lee — Set appropriate margins, padding and border-collapse in the stylesheet (and fix the errors that a [validator](http://validator.w3.org/) would pick up). The spacing you had before was the result of quirks mode bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the table the following styles:

```
table{
   position:relative;
   left:-50%;
   margin-left:450px;
}
```

Does that center it?